Can you fill an espresso boiler with soda water to increase crème?
I’ve read that the bubbles in crème are from CO2 released by the coffee grounds. The CO2 dissolves in the pressurized water during extraction, then foams as it comes out of the portafilter. It’s a similar  process as beer when the can is opened.
If the espresso boiler was filled with soda water, there would be more CO2 and (potentially) thicker crème.
Has anyone tried this? How stupid is this idea?
EDIT I tried it. No explosions. I think it made the creme bigger in volume, but the tiny bubbles coalesced into larger bubbles which broke faster, so the creme didn't last as long. Definately not worth the effort.
EDIT A surprising result: using soda water lowers my boiler temperature by 25C. Whaaaat? Turns out the heating element is controlled by boiler pressure, not temperature. The heater turns on and off to maintain boiler pressure at 15psi.This corresponds to a tap water temperature of about 120C.
If the boiler is filled with soda water, the added pressure provided by the CO2 "boiling" out of the soda water shuts the heater off at 25C lower temperature.
Lower temperature will change extraction. I couldn't do a side-by-each taste comparison because it took too long to cool, empty and re-fill the boiler. But it certainly made a difference in the appearance of the creme:

If an espresso machine was temperature-controlled instead of pressure-controlled, soda water could cause over-pressure if the safety valve malfunctioned. This could wreck the machine and cause personal injury.
So, "YES" this is a stupid idea.
Idiots learn from their mistakes. Wise men learn from idiots.

If you used store bought soda water make sure to descale your machine now as I'm sure there is some mineral residue left inside.

Soda water is water with CO2 in it. There are no minerals in it. "Mineral Water" (like Perrier) is something more like hard tap water. It has sodium, calcium and magnesium as well as the CO2 "sparkles".

Soda water is a term used to describe all kinds of carbonated water, with and without added minerals. If your soda water is store bought, I would wager that it is not merely distilled water with added carbon dioxide. If the packaging gives any sort of indication about the mineral content, it would be wise to descale your machine if it is significantly higher than 300ppm, as the recommended range for brewing coffee is 75-250ppm with a target of 150ppm.

I don't think this will work. Firstly, most of the CO2 will escape when the water gets heated, possibly damaging the boiler, as well as depositing minerals in the boiler.
Then, if there's any fizzy left, it will probably interfere with extraction, as the coffee grounds are perfect nucleation sites.
In short, it would be interesting if you could try it and report back, but don't do it with a machine you value a lot :)
Maybe slightly safer to try as pour-over.

I have never tried this, and I wouldn't. The gas in the soda water might cause unexpected results when pumping at pressure, like sputtering or splattering. In the worst case, this could hurt you, while in the best case, it could ruin your drink and make a big mess.
Another possible risk is to your machine. If your machine contains a three way solenoid to extract water from the puck after brewing, using soda water can cause a difference of pressure within the puck. This could clog either the solenoid line or the brew head.
Instead it might be smarter to brew with plain water and then steam soda water to add to it after, like you would milk for a latte. This protects you, your brewing space, and your machine and shouldn't prove much (if at all) different from pushing soda water through the puck.
